# Save inital value of input in vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, input, axios

I have a props that render into my child component, and i've displayed the value of props into my `input`. The initial value would be the 
**student ID**

[image]

```
<form @submit.prevent="insertScore"> 
  <td v-for> 
     <input type="text" :value="classlist.id" />
  </td>
     <button type="submit">save</button>
</form>
```

in my data function

```
  props: ["classlists"],
  data() {
    return {
      form: new Form({
        studentId: [] 
      })
    };
  },
//insertScore
```

**How do i save my initial value into my `form.studentId`, and i also need this to pass into my store controller in laravel**

This is my classlists props

```
[
 {"student": "Ebony Hand",           "gender": "female",   "id": 1 },
 {"student": "Maryse Orn",           "gender": "male",     "id": 2 }, 
 {"student": "Dr. Maverick Steuber", "gender": "male",     "id": 3 }, 
 {"student": "Korbin Rutherford",    "gender": "male",     "id": 4 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

put in a `created` (or `mounted`) lifecycle method and set it there.
like so:

```
created(){
   this.form.studentId = this.studentId (assuming thats what the prop is called)
```

Comment: ,the returned value is still 0 and my `classlists` props is
 ` {  "student": "Ebony Hand","id": 1 },  "student": "Maryse Orn", "id": 2 }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the v-model directive to create two-way data bindings on form input, textarea, and select elements.

```
  <input v-model="message" placeholder="edit me">
```

To use v-model with form.studentId[n]:

1. form should be a data property.
2. form.studentId should be an array.

Then you can do the following:

```
 <div v-for='classlist in classlists'>
  <input v-model="form.studentId[classlist.id]">
 </div>



   data() {
     form: {
       studentId: []
     }
  }
```

Comment: combining `v-model` and `:value` will give an error and the initial value is already given. What i need is to pass the initial value into new data in my `form.studentId`